# How to compare a Geometry result from Geometry.Parse with Geometry.Empty?

Tags: c#, wpf, geometry

The have a geometry shape class implementation that looks something like this:

```
    private readonly IShapeModel _shape;

    public Shape(IShapeModel shape) : base(shape)
    {
        _shape = shape;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Specific geometry data of the shape
    /// </summary>
    public string GeometryData => _shape.GeometryData;

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the <see cref="Geometry"/> for this shape
    /// </summary>
    public Geometry Geometry => Geometry.Parse(GeometryData);
```

As you can see I provide a Model to the shape and allows it to return a Geometry object with the standard Parse method provided by Geometry.

The code works perfectly and returns an Empty Geometry when no GeometryData is set.

Now I want to test it with something like this:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void AccessGeometryPropertyWithNoGeometryDataSetShouldReturnEmpty()
    {
        var shape = new TestShapeModel {GeometryData = null};
        _shapeViewModel = new Shape(shape);
        var expected = Geometry.Empty;
        var actual = _shapeViewModel.Geometry;
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
```

Although the problem is Geometry.Empty seems to return a new instance that is not equal to the result of the Parsed instance.

Although both objects are identical. I get this result:
Additional information: Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<>. Actual:<>.

As I came up with this:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void AccessGeometryPropertyWithNoGeometryDataSetShouldReturnEmpty()
    {
        var shape = new TestShapeModel {GeometryData = null};
        _shapeViewModel = new Shape(shape);
        Assert.IsTrue(IsEmptyGeometry(_shapeViewModel.Geometry));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Check if Geometry is empty by comparing Empty Bounds.
    /// </summary>
    private static bool IsEmptyGeometry(Geometry geometry)
    {
        var result = false;
        var expected = Geometry.Empty;
        if (geometry != null)
        {
            result = (geometry.Bounds == expected.Bounds);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Is there a better approach to solve this? I would expect something in the framework itself to compare with Geometry.Empty without overriding Equals or implementing this code above.

Comment: [`Geometry.IsEmpty()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.geometry.isempty(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Geometry is not implemented by you at all, you could take your IsEmptyGeometry method and make it an extension method, and use it to make your Assertion in a "good looking" way.

```
public static class GeometryExtensions
{
    public static bool IsEmpty(this Geometry geometry)
    {
        var result = false;
        var expected = Geometry.Empty;

        if (geometry != null)
        {
            result = (geometry.Bounds == expected.Bounds);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Then instead of doing this:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestEmptyGeometry()
    {
        var shape = new TestShapeModel { GeometryData = null };
        _shapeViewModel = new Shape(shape);
        var expected = Geometry.Empty;
        var actual = _shapeViewModel.Geometry;
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
```

You could do this:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestEmptyGeometry()
    {
        var shape = new TestShapeModel { GeometryData = null };
        _shapeViewModel = new Shape(shape);
        var actual = _shapeViewModel.Geometry;
        Assert.IsTrue(actual.IsEmpty());
    }
```

Comment: Using an extension method indeed makes it more elegant for testing. I might consider changing / removing the null check in this case. I will up vote this answer to be best suitable solution.

Comment: Oddly enough I totally overlooked the fact there is already an IsEmpty() method within the framework like Damien_The_Unbeliever mentioned. It eventually made this solution obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

Assert.Equals uses equals comparation between objects, so you must override the Equals method of System.Object to make it work by comparing two Geometry objects. I don't know your implementation of Geometry, so I'm gonna assume how the essential works trough what you explained.

I'm assuming that what makes one Geometry to be like other is them having the same Bounds. In your case it must be more complex than that, so consider it in my example.

Here's the tip of what to do in your Geometry class.

```
public class Geometry
{
    // I don't know what is the implementation of bounds, so 
    // I'm just assuming that is something comparable here.
    public Rectangle Bounds { get; set; }

    // Here's your definition of Geometry.Empty, from what I understood.
    public static Geometry Empty
    {
        get
        {
            return new Geometry { Bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0) };
        }
    }

    // Here is the key: you must override the default operators of equality
    // and difference to make comparations to work, because internally it will
    // use them.
    public static bool operator ==(Geometry left, Geometry right)
    {
        if (left == null && right == null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (left != null && right != null)
        {
            return left.Bounds == right.Bounds;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Geometry left, Geometry right)
    {
        if (left == null && right == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (left != null && right != null)
        {
            return left.Bounds != right.Bounds;
        }

        return true;
    }

    // I recommend you to override Equals method of
    // System.Object too. For Assert.AreEqual to work,
    // actually this method will be used.
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var objAsGeometry = obj as Geometry;

        if (obj == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return objAsGeometry.Bounds == this.Bounds;
    }

    // GetHashCode is used in some types of comparations too,
    // altough not in your case with Assert.AreEqual.
    // If you want to make a fully comparable object, 
    // be sure to override it too, with all conditions used
    // to compare one Geometry object with other.
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Bounds.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

By doing that, a test that compare two Geometry.Empty objects must pass:

```
[TestClass]
public class GeometryTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestTwoEmptyGeometries()
    {
        var geometry1 = Geometry.Empty;
        var geometry2 = Geometry.Empty;

        // Pass
        Assert.AreEqual(geometry1, geometry2);
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect their talking about [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.geometry(v=vs.110).aspx) `Geometry` class, i.e. not one of their own.

Comment: Well, if Geometry is not implemented by him, then Assert.Equals is not going to work at all, because the class itself is not comparable with that method. Then, I would suggest taking this method IsEmpty and making it an extension method, so he could call Geometry.IsEmpty() instead.